# Connection Between Moreau Envelope and the Conjugate

Tags: convex-analysis, definition, convex-optimization, duality-theorems, proximal-operators

Let $f$ be a proper, lower semicontinuous function, then the [Moreau envelope](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.07144.pdf) is given by:

> $e_\lambda g(x) := \inf_y \{g(y) + \dfrac{1}{2\lambda}\|x-y\|^2\}$

Recall that the Fenchel conjugate is:

> Given $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$
>
> $f^*(x) := \sup_y \{x^Ty - f(y)\}$

Are these two definitions connected somehow?

It seems that if $g(y) = -x^Ty$, and $f(y) = \dfrac{1}{2\lambda}\|x-y\|^2$, the two definitions will coincide.

So can we say that the Moreau envelope of $g(y) = -x^Ty$ is the Fenchel conjugate of $f(y) = \dfrac{1}{2\lambda}\|x-y\|^2$?

Comment: Up to a negative sign, yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they're related! Indeed, it's not too hard to show that
$$
e_1(g)^* = g^* + \left(\frac{1}{2}\|.\|_2^2\right)^* = g^* + \frac{1}{2}\|.\|_2^2.
$$

More generally, it holds that

$$
(g \Box f)^* = g^* + f^*,\; \forall f, g \in \Gamma_0(\mathcal H).
$$
where $(g\Box f)(x) := \inf_{y \in \mathcal H}g(y) + f(x-y)$ defines the *infimal-convolution* of $f$ and $g$.

**Bonus:** $e_\lambda(g)$ is smooth with derivative given by
$$\nabla e_\lambda g(x) = \text{prox}_\lambda g(x) := \text{argmin}_{y \in \mathcal H}g(y) + \frac{1}{2\lambda}\|x-y\|_2^2,
$$
the *proximal operator* of $g$.

You can learn more on these things from this [one-page manuscript](https://people.ok.ubc.ca/bauschke/Research/68.pdf) from Bauschke.

**N.B.:** $\Gamma_0(\mathcal H) := $ the cone of *proper convex lower-semicontinous* functions on a hilbert space $\mathcal H$.

Comment: Do you have any favorite convex analysis books other than Bauschke and Combettes?

Comment: There is also the Rockafellar classic which I presume you already know. It contains fundamental results like stuff on maximally monotone operators, etc. On the practical side (convex optimization, rates of convergence, etc.), there are classic books by Nemirovski and also Nesterov.

Comment: lsc is a much weaker notion than continuity. Roughly speaking it means that  for a point fixed point $x_0$, $f(x)$ is either  close to or less than $f(x_0)$ whenever $x$ is "close to" $x_0$. For metric spaces, this reduces to saying $\limsup_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x) \le f(x_0)$. See complete definition here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity#Formal_definition. Some characterizations are given here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity#Properties